# How do I join three fields from three tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, join, syntax

I have three fields from three different tables that I would like to join together.

company FROM company,
title FROM jobs,
Description FROM jobcategory

I would like to have these three fields join together and listed sequentially to the right of the prvious field as follows:

Company | Title | Description

This is the best I can do as for providing information regarding the databases Keys...

```
CREATE TABLE `company` (
  `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`companyID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=117 ;


CREATE TABLE `jobcategory` (
  `JobCategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `CategoryName` text,
  `Description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`JobCategoryID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_JobCategoryID` (`JobCategoryID`),
  KEY `index_JobCategoryID` (`JobCategoryID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `company` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `companyID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `jobCategoryID` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I tried running a query commented below, I received the following error.

> "Error 1054 (42S22) : Unknown column 'Company.ID' in "on clause'

What is the proper syntax to execute this query?

Comment: Did you try google? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: That was obviously the first place I've gone haha. I've looked at that page multiple times. It just visually doesn't make sense to me unfortunately, Im incredibly new to working with MySQL.

Comment: You kinda need to provide the foreign key references at the minimum that each table have with each other, else no-one will be able to help you. :P

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how your keys are set up, but assuming JOBS has foreign keys referencing the COMPANY and JOBCATEGORY tables:

```
SELECT COMPANY.COMPANY, JOBS.TITLE, JOBCATEGORY.DESCRIPTION<br>
FROM COMPANY 
INNER JOIN JOBS ON COMPANY.ID=JOBS.COMPANY_ID
INNER JOIN JOBCATEGORY ON JOBCATEGORY.ID=JOBS.JOBCATEGORY_ID
```

Comment: That unfortunately did not work. I'll post a screenshot displaying the error I received from attempting to run that query.